# Partition by custom column name using row_number over partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition, customcolumn

I have a custom column on my query:

```
CASE 
    WHEN Table.Column0 LIKE '%x%' 
        THEN 'A' 
        ELSE 'B' 
END AS 'CustomColumn',
```

When I try to partition the data in the query using:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Table.Column1, Table.Column2 ORDER BY Table.Column 3 ASC) AS g2
```

It works perfectly, but I would also like to add the `CustomColumn` as criteria for partitioning to further split out the data. Even if I try to add it in `[]`, SQL Server simply tells me

> Invalid column name 'CustomColumn'

but the column is showing under the correct name in the data preview.

Is there a way to add it in to the `row_number() over (partition...` statement ?

Comment: Don't use Square brackets. Just include the literal case expression. `partition by case when... end, column2`

Comment: Yes, but you have the whole `case when ...` thing in the row number, you cannot add the alias of course. Also, please avoid string aliases like 'Alias* in general

Answer (score 2):

The name of the custom column is not visible in the SELECT, WHERE, or GROUP BY clause of the query where it's defined (only in ORDER BY).  So you need to use a inline subquery or common table expression (CTE), like this

```
with q as
(
  select *, case when t.Column0 like '%x%' then 'A' else 'B' end as CustomColumn
  from t
)
select *, row_number() over (partition by CustomColumn order by Column1) rn
from q
```

Comment: Thank you David, I tried that but have same problem on a different level. 

I should also have been clearer in my original post, the CustomColumn in created in the SELECT statement at the very start and then referenced in the partition clause.

I have re-written the query to start with this basic structure:

WITH q AS
(
SELECT 
table.column1,
...
CASE WHEN table.column0 LIKE .... AS CustomColumn
FROM table
)

SELECT 
*,
ROW_NUMBER..... AS rn
FROM q

WHERE rn = 1

The WHERE statement is again where the query breaks, telling me "Invalid Column Name". Tried with q.rn or rn.

Comment: Then you need an additional CTE.